# Determining the big-O runtimes of loop with inner loop repeat time is const

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a function

```
for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
{
  b[i]=0;
  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  { 
    b[i]=a[j+i]
  }
}
```

I need to calculate big-O of above function. My answers is:
Inner loop run `5n` time => `O(n)`.
So the total complexity is `O(n)`. I think I have a mistake in my calculations, but I don't know where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you haven't made any mistake. You are correct in thinking so and is your solution perfect!

The outer-loop will run n-times and the inner loop runs for 5(constant) times.

Therefore, the loops complexity will be O(5*n) = O(n) and the other statements are of constant time-complexity.

Since, **5*n times execution of program means O(n) time-complexity of your program**.

Comment: my teacher give a requirement which i must  change the function to have min  complexity . i don't any ideal to slove them. can you help me

Comment: Post a new question for the same and pass the link to me over here! I'll try to help you as much as possible. Best wishes @user2083943.

Comment: now i must make a program have  target same above program but new programe have lowest complexity